# Why is my wordpress site on GAE not being cached?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, caching, memcached

I installed wordpress 3.8.1 on GAE - transfered from a WP-MU installation on another host. I installed GAE plugin which is working but mentions I should also install batcache and memcached plugins. So I installed them both but they don't seem to be working- I get no debug output in `<head>` section, response is 200 and site is generally slow. What can I do to enable caching? Here are the response headers after 2 reloads with `curl -i`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Cookie
X-Pingback: http://www.websiteinquestion.com/xmlrpc.php
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Sun, 09 Feb 2014 23:20:32 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Cache-Control: private
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,80:quic
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

There is some debug output when enabled:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /base/data/home/apps/s~xxx/xxx.stringofnumbers/wordpress/wp-content/object-cache.php on line 374
```

Here is the app.yaml

```
application: xxxxx
version: xxx
runtime: php
threadsafe: no
default_expiration: "2d"
api_version: 1
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 0
  max_idle_instances: 1
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: 15000ms
```

in wp-config.php I added

```
define('WP_CACHE', true);
```

I tried viewing the memcache stats on GAE console but I can't find the viewer anywhere. In settings memcache is set to shared mode.

Comment: the viewer is in the admin console, the last item under data is 'memcache viewer'

Comment: Thanks, I found it - I was looking at cloud.google.com but should have looked at appengine.google.com
Sad part is the cache seems to be working (though plugin still doesn't output anything) but the site is still slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After disabling a **RSS widget** in administration, site is being cached correctly.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I can't find any RSS widget to disable... There are links to RSS feeds on the pages by default in the theme I'm using, but in the admin there is no active RSS widget to be found...

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the batcache config devised by Google was the cause of the problem. In the instructions given on https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress, it says:

> In your wp-config.php file, add the following lines at the end of the file:
>
> ```
> $batcache = [
>   'seconds'=>0,
>   'max_age'=>30*60, // 30 minutes
>   'debug'=>false
> ];
> ```

If you do that, you get a warning:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in
>   /Users/per/google-cloud/appocentric-wordpress/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php
>   on line 199

However, if you move the batcache config lines to just before the line that reads

> /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

in wp-config, it works! So trust the Wordpress guys rather than Google, in this case...

===============

I also found a fix for the Undefined Offset issue you describe (source [http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fix-for-notice-undefined-offset-1](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fix-for-notice-undefined-offset-1?replies=3)).

Memcached Memcached plugin version 2.0.2 gives the following error message:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/wp-content/object-cache.php on line 374
```

This results from only having the server listed as the default without a port:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" }
```

There is no port listed to populate the port variable in line 374 resulting in the Undefined offset notice. Here is line 374:

```
list ( $node, $port ) = explode(':', $server);
```

The solution is modify line 365 from:

```
$buckets = array('127.0.0.1');
```

to:

```
$buckets = array('127.0.0.1:11211');
```

This has been fixed in the source and will be available in future versions > 2.0.2